# MYSQL remove enclosing string

Tags: mysql, string

I have a column in database which has HTML format data.

```
<div id="subtitle"><h2>Quisque cursus metus vitae, sem massa mattis sem.</h2></div>
```

I don't have access to how the database gets updated, is there a way I can strip the enclosing `div` via SQL? I would like to remove the enclosing `<div id="subtitle">` tag to just have this instead in the column:

```
<h2>Quisque cursus metus vitae, sem massa mattis sem.</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL for this sort of thing is not really ideal. You would probably be better off doing it with a programming language. That being said, under the assumption that the enclosing div **always** looks like `<div id="subtitle">` and `</div>`, you could probably do something like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(myTable.myColumn, '<div id="subtitle">', ''),'</div>','');
```

I've not tested that. I actually don't even know if it is possible to nest the REPLACE function like that, but give it a try and see if it works for you.